# Usecontext returning undefined - React native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I want a page with a list of data fetched from backend. Each values in the list will have a "Get more details" button clicking on which each items individual data should get displayed. I'm, trying to pass the items data to next page using useContext hook, but the data is showing as undefined in the next page.

GetOrders.js

```
export const orderContext = React.createContext()
const GetOrders = ({ navigation }) => {

renderOrdersData = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <orderContext.Provider value={ item }>

      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => showAddress(item)} style={[styles.item]}>
        <View style={styles.textstyles}>
       
          <View style={styles.contentstyle}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>Name: {item.customer.name}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.title}>Quantity: {item.orders.quantity} </Text>
            <Text style={styles.title}>Contact: {item.customer.contact}</Text>
          </View>
        
          <View style={styles.paidbuttonstyles} >
            <Button title="Get more details"
              onPress={() => navigation.navigate('CustomerOrder') }
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      </orderContext.Provider>


    );
  };

return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
          <Text style={styles.textcss}> Your Pending orders are </Text>
          <FlatList
            style={styles.listcolor}
            data={orders}
            renderItem={renderOrdersData}
          />
        </SafeAreaView>
      );
}
```

CustomerOrder.js

```
import { orderContext } from './GetOrders'
const CustomerOrder = ({ navigation }) => {

  let items = useContext(orderContext)


  showAddress = () => {

    console.log(" inside showadress" + items);

    console.log(" inside showadress json " + JSON.stringify(items));
   }

   return (
     <View style={styles.dismissbuttonstyles} >
        <Button title="Get Customer address"
          onPress={() => showAddress()}
        />
      </View>
   );
}
```

When ever i press "GetCustomer address" button, I get an exception

```
[Tue Sep 01 2020 19:20:50.443]  LOG       inside showadressundefined
[Tue Sep 01 2020 19:20:50.459]  LOG       inside showadress json undefined
[Tue Sep 01 2020 19:20:50.461]  ERROR    TypeError: undefined is not an object
```

Any help would be appreciated? Thanks

Comment: Where have you used `CustomerOrder`? Your `CustomerOrder` component has to be under `orderContext.Provider`.

Comment: Yes. Please check my return statement in getOrder.js file. The tag starts with <orderContext.provider>

Comment: Where? I don't see any. You're using a navigator to navigate to that route. But I don't necessarily see where you have defined the component?
Does the navigator support pass props to the route? I think you could pass via navigator the data to your route.

Comment: Thank you. passing data via navigator worked.